# TreeTable in SAP UI5 with no child row

Tags: sapui5

Is it possible to have a tree table in SAP UI5 with no child row. But still show the  ">" against the parent. On expanding it will show nothing.

Answer (score 0):

**Sure,** simply don't add any parameters to the binding of your columns.

```html
<TreeTable
    id="someId"
    rows="{ path: '/GroupNodes' }"> <!-- Your binding here -->
    <columns>

        <Column>
            <template>
                <m:Text text="{Grpid}"></m:Text>
            </template>
        </Column>

    </columns>
</TreeTable>
```

Which produces the following:

[image: Uncollapsable TreeTable]